# Does default_if_none have any use in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

From the Django docs,

> Generally, if a variable doesn't
>   exist, the template system inserts the
>   value of the
>   TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID setting,
>   which is set to '' (the empty string)
>   by default.
>
> Filters that are applied to an invalid
>   variable will only be applied if
>   TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID is set to
>   '' (the empty string). If
>   TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID is set to
>   any other value, variable filters will
>   be ignored.
>
> This behavior is slightly different
>   for the if, for and regroup template
>   tags. If an invalid variable is
>   provided to one of these template
>   tags, the variable will be interpreted
>   as None. Filters are always applied to
>   invalid variables within these
>   template tags.

If an invalid variable always gets translated to '', for template tags and filters other than *if*, *for* and *regroup*, then what good does the template filter **default_if_none** do? Obsolete?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a difference between an invalid variable and one that exists but has a value of `None`.

Consider the following context:

```
{'apple':'green','banana':None}`
```

In your template `{{ apple }}` resolves to `green`, while `{{ banana }}` resolves to `None`, and `{{ orange }}` resolves to `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID`.

Now consider `{{ banana|default_if_none:'yellow' }}` and you should see the use of the `default_if_none` tag.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a case where I have used `default_if_none` a few times.  I'm querying a secondary database in which I have no control and I'm displaying the data in the template.  Most of the times the data looks fine but sometimes, the data value will show `None`.  In that case, I will use the filter as:

```
{{ data_value|default_if_none:"N/A" }}
```

The general public and users of site doesn't usually understand what the `None` value means, by replacing it with a more friendly word, the filter `default_if_none` comes in handy.

Comment: Take care when you want to join more than one filter. For example: `value|upper|default_if_none:"-"` not work, you should put: `value|default_if_none:"-"|upper`

Answer (score 0):

I have a Django model with a method returning the the number of days a trade has been open (an integer). For the first 24 hours it returns 0. However, once the trade is closed, it returns None.

In this situation, the distinction between default and default_if_none is important... I need to use default_if_none... otherwise, for the first 24 hours a trade is open, it looks as if they were already closed (because zero is falsy).

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.